# Logo is not visible properly in Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, splash-screen

I have a logo which I have added in my Splash Screen, but it is not visible properly when I am launching the app.

Tried everything I know but still facing the same issue, while launching the app.

Can anyone please look into the code and tell me what is the issue as in logs there is no error and everything is working fine, I have a problem with logo only.

below are the codes and screenshot:

splash_activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashImg"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/splashText"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/splashText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/developed_in_india_with"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/heart"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/splashText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.droidsaurav.teachersclub;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView splashImage;
TextView splashText, heart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    splashImage = findViewById(R.id.splashImg);
    splashText = findViewById(R.id.splashText);
    heart = findViewById(R.id.heart);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent regIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(regIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
}
```

Screenshot of the splashScreen:

[image]

I tried to decrease the size of the logo as well but still it is not visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I got the solution, I was trying somethings and then I removed the logo from **mipmap-anydpi-v26** and **mipmap-anydpi-v33** folders and then again launched the app and it is working fine.

I let the logo remain in other folders except that two.

Find the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).